# Create a dynamic Tv guide in PHP

Tags: php

I want to creat a simple Tv Guide for my Tv site..
I have the guide that looks like this

5.30-6.00: Program 1

6.00 -7.00: Program 2

My question is simple.. how do I set that at 5.30 the current program will be Program 1 (somthing like.. You are currently watching program 1) 
Please remember timezones in your answer

Comment: what is the source of tv-guide? where do you get the data? where are you going to store the data? do you have any db structure?

Comment: @heximal Probably an XML file

Comment: Though the question is simple, it is woefully incomplete.  One very correct answer is 'through several hundred (thousand if you include all of the UI as well) lines of code.'  You can't expect anyone to write your entire solution for you.  You'll need to provide your data/db schema and more details of what 'setting' the current program means.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JavaScript which use the

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours() + '.' + date.getMinutes;
```

and with it, can make an ajax call to get the actual tv-program's name from your php script.